# How to Extract parameters from captured beacon frame

Tags: networking, wireless, python, packet-analyzer

So I was able to extract the SSID and Mac Address from the captured Beacon Frame stored in pkt.

I used scapy library's sniff function to capture the beacon frame.

I did this to capture the mentioned parameters as:

- pkt.addr2     #for Mac Address
- pkt.info      #for SSID

Now I am stuck as I want to extract other parameters also.
the list of parameters that I need are:
Channel Bandwith

1. Frequncy
2. RSSI
3. Type of Protection (WPA-psk/WPA2/etc.)

Please help me by either giving me the attributes to directly extract the above parameters or let me know the whole structure of the packet so that I can extract other parameters also if I need to in future.

Thanks.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu as my OS

Answer (score 0):

You might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10818661/scapy-retrieving-rssi-from-wifi-packets) to be of interest.  There is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10841875) there claiming that the RSSI is in the notdecoded part of the packet and they describe how to retrieve it.  Also, how you put the card in capture mode may effect the presence of the RSSI info field.

I don't think frequency information is stored in the capture, but the type of protection should be in the Dot11Elt ID field.  Some random github hosted script that parses [this](https://github.com/0x90/iSniff/blob/master/iSniff.py).